# Not able to insert records from one table to another table using Pyspark SQL in AWS Glue job

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I am unable to insert records from one table to another table using Pyspark SQL in AWS Glue job. Its not prompting any error as well..

Table1 name : details_info

```
spark.sql('select count(*) from details_info').show(); 

count: 50000
```

Table2 name : goals_info

```
spark.sql('select count(*) from goals_info').show(); 

count: 0
```

I am trying to insert data from "details_info" table to "goals_info" table with below querie

```
spark.sql("INSERT INTO goals_info SELECT * FROM details_info")

I am expecting the count of goals_info as 50000 but it is showing me as 0 after 
executing above sql statement

spark.sql('select count(*) from goals_info').show();
count: 0
```

code block is executing with out throwing any error but data is not inserting as count is showing as 0. Could anybody help me understand what might be the reason?

I even tried with write.insertInto() pyspark method , but the count is still showing a zero

```
 view_df = spark.table("details_info")
 view_df.write.insertInto("goals_info")
```

Comment: Are these tables `hive` tables or some other DB you are connecting to read the tables in AWS glue? or these exists in AWS Glue Catalog ?

Comment: @Frosty details_info is temporary table in glue session created using df.createOrReplaceTempView(details_info)

"goals_info" is created by using spark.sql as below 

spark.sql("CREATE TABLE goals_info AS SELECT * FROM details_info where 1=2")